# In Vim, how do I get the total number of matches after doing a search?

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if there exists an event or option in vim that detects if there are currently words being highlighted as the result of user doing searching (for example, with `:/`).

Basically, my Vimscript wants to do something like:

```
if (search highlight is turned on) and (there is at least one match)
    find out the total number of matches
    find out the index of current match
```

Any idea? Thanks.

*P.S.* The reason why I want this is because whenever I do a search, I have to pay attention to the line number change on the side to be able to tell if the search has reached the bottom of the file. I'd like some sort of indication, maybe on the status bar, that the current occurrence (highlighted word) is, for example, 5/20 out of all occurrences in the file.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ingo-karkat I didn't include all the background info because I wanted to ideally figure this out myself and felt like I just needed a little hint. Please see the updates on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a plugin that does this: [IndexedSearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1682): shows  'Nth match out of M'  at every search (index of match+total # matches).

Also, have a look at my [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634); it has to be triggered via a mapping, but then shows a lot of information about the (current and overall) matches.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need 15+ reps to be able to upvote answers.

Comment: @melonccoli: Don't forget to eventually accept the best answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it.

Answer (score 2):

`:h v:hlsearch`

That variable tells you whether search highlighting is on.

```
if v:hlsearch && search(pattern, 'cn')
    // do stuff
endif
```

Edit: Updating answer

In order to get the number of matches, one crude way of doing it would be :

```
redir => num_matches
:%s/pattern//n
redir END
```

Now the variable num_matches holds the output of `:%s/pattern//gn`, you can parse it.

Another probably more reliable way to get it would be to actually use `search(pattern, 'c')` and cycle through all the matches within a loop until you come back to the first, which would give you your desired data.

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for though. `hlsearch` tells you whether vim will highlight the search terms. What I need is a variable that tells me if the search terms are being highlighted at any given point. In other words, something that indicates if there's a match to the search query.

Comment: `:%s/pattern//n` would give you the number of matches for `pattern`, but I am not sure how we can tap into it with vimscript.

Comment: If Vim saves `pattern` somewhere then Vimscript should be able to retrieve that value and subsequently run the command you showed to find out the number of matches.

Comment: Vim saves the last searched `pattern` in the `/` register and you can access it using `let last_search = @/`

Answer (score 2):

I like your idea and have coded a solution for it.  It has to do a fair bit of work in Vimscript, but it actually runs reasonably well on a 8000-line file.

Suggestions if you want to try this yourself:

It triggers a function call on CursorHold.  My function checks to see if we are currently on a match line:

```
let this_line = getline('.')
if match(this_line, @/) >= 0
    ...
```

If we are, then I loop through all the lines in the file, using `match()` to count the number of matching lines, and find the index of the current occurrence.  The only other function I had to use was `line()`.

I will push my script up soon, but this might be enough for you to work with.  Thanks for the idea!

Update: Although searching the whole file is quite a lot of work, it seems to perform quite well on a modern machine.  In the current version, I only trigger the search when the cursor is on the start of a match, and only if the number of lines in the buffer is below a threshold (default 10,000).

Update: My script is at [show_search_occurrence.vim](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/show_search_occurrence.vim)

Comment: My code is [here](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/show_search_occurrence.vim).  It echoes the message, so you may want to adapt it for the statusline.

Comment: Update: Implemented the statusline version now.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need 15+ reps to be able to upvote answers.